# translation file to bring in multiple rows from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Please can someone assist I cannot for the life of me figure out how to adjust my translation file so that the xml to follow is brought in with multiple lines per supplier and multiple suppliers on one xml. In other words, I need to bring the file into our ERP system so that a new purchase order is created for each supplier in the xml but the order lines are grouped per supplier accordingly (for example Supplier A has multiple lines in the xml and Supplier B has multiple lines. All those that belong to A must be on the same purchase order for A and likewise for B)

Here is a sample of the xml:

```
<rows>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>LIY0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>5021616</ITEM>
<QTY>528</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>1</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>5.25</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>LIY0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>5021816</ITEM>
<QTY>222</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>2</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>5.90</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>WOR0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>650616</ITEM>
<QTY>129</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>9</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>4.46</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>WOR0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>650610</ITEM>
<QTY>129</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>3</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>3.5</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
</rows>
```

Here is the translation file I have created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<PostPurchaseOrders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderHeader> 
      <xsl:for-each select = "rows/row">
      <CustomerPoNumber><xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NO"/></CustomerPoNumber> 
      <Supplier><xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER"/></Supplier>
          <OrderDate><xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_DATE"/></OrderDate>
          <DueDate><xsl:value-of select="DUE_DATE"/></DueDate>
         <Warehouse><xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/></Warehouse>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </OrderHeader> 
      <OrderDetails>
     <xsl:for-each select = "rows/row">
       <StockLine>
         <PurchaseOrderLine><xsl:value-of select="LINE_ITEM_NO"/></PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode><xsl:value-of select="ITEM"/></StockCode>
            <Warehouse><xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/></Warehouse>
           <OrderQty><xsl:value-of select="QTY"/></OrderQty>
           <Price><xsl:value-of select="PURCHASEPRICE"/></Price>
          </StockLine>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </OrderDetails>       
       </Orders>
<PostPurchaseOrders>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help as to how I can change my translation file to loop or something so that many lines are brought into one purchase order for each supplier would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE

Here is what I need the xml transformed into for our ERP system:

```
<PostPurchaseOrder>
<Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
        <Supplier>LIY0001</Supplier>
        <CustomerPoNumber>example po</CustomerPoNumber>
        <OrderDate>2013-02-03</OrderDate>
        <Warehouse>A1</Warehouse>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
        <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>1</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>12022</StockCode>
            <OrderQty>10</OrderQty>
        </StockLine>
        <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>2</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>15014</StockCode>
            <OrderQty>15</OrderQty>
        </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</PostPurchaseOrders>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what the target XML needs to look like?

Comment: Hi @DanielHaley

Please see required above. I am receiving the one xml on my side but from what I understand our ERP system can take in multiple suppliers if they simply follow on after the example in a new header section with detail section attached so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your expected output, it is a bit tricky knowing exactly what you want, but it does look like you want to group orders by supplier. Grouping items is a common problem in XSLT, and in XSLT1.0 you use a technique called Muenchian Grouping to do this.

If you are grouping **row** elements by supplier, you would start off by defining the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="suppliers" match="row" use="SUPPLIER"/>
```

Then, to get distinct suppliers, you select the **row** elements which occur first in the group for the key using their given supplier

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('suppliers',SUPPLIER)[1])]" 
   mode="header"/>
```

Note the use of **mode** here, this is because in the final XSLT there will be two templates matching **row** elements and you need a way to distinguish between them.

Finally, for each 'header' **row** element (i.e. the **row** element with the first occurrence of a given supplier) you can then get the rows that make up the group like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('suppliers', SUPPLIER)"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="suppliers" match="row" use="SUPPLIER"/>

   <xsl:template match="rows">
      <PostPurchaseOrders>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('suppliers',SUPPLIER)[1])]" mode="header"/>
      </PostPurchaseOrders>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row" mode="header">
      <Orders>
         <OrderHeader>
            <CustomerPoNumber>
               <xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NO"/>
            </CustomerPoNumber>
            <Supplier>
               <xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER"/>
            </Supplier>
            <OrderDate>
               <xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_DATE"/>
            </OrderDate>
            <DueDate>
               <xsl:value-of select="DUE_DATE"/>
            </DueDate>
            <Warehouse>
               <xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/>
            </Warehouse>
         </OrderHeader>
         <OrderDetails>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('suppliers', SUPPLIER)"/>
         </OrderDetails>
      </Orders>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="row">
      <StockLine>
         <PurchaseOrderLine>
            <xsl:value-of select="LINE_ITEM_NO"/>
         </PurchaseOrderLine>
         <StockCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM"/>
         </StockCode>
         <Warehouse>
            <xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/>
         </Warehouse>
         <OrderQty>
            <xsl:value-of select="QTY"/>
         </OrderQty>
         <Price>
            <xsl:value-of select="PURCHASEPRICE"/>
         </Price>
      </StockLine>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XSLT, the following is output:

```
<PostPurchaseOrders>
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CustomerPoNumber>
         <Supplier>LIY0001</Supplier>
         <OrderDate>2013-02-14</OrderDate>
         <DueDate>2013-05-13</DueDate>
         <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>1</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>5021616</StockCode>
            <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
            <OrderQty>528</OrderQty>
            <Price>5.25</Price>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>2</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>5021816</StockCode>
            <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
            <OrderQty>222</OrderQty>
            <Price>5.90</Price>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CustomerPoNumber>
         <Supplier>WOR0001</Supplier>
         <OrderDate>2013-02-14</OrderDate>
         <DueDate>2013-05-13</DueDate>
         <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>9</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>650616</StockCode>
            <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
            <OrderQty>129</OrderQty>
            <Price>4.46</Price>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>3</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>650610</StockCode>
            <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
            <OrderQty>129</OrderQty>
            <Price>3.5</Price>
         </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</PostPurchaseOrders>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C.
Thank you so much will give it a bash and report back.

Comment: Hi Tim C

The file seems to work perfectly but please can you assist with one adjustment? In addition to a new order per supplier a new order must be created per supplier per warehouse. In other words a PO from WOR0001 for A4 and then another from WOR0001 for A5? Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It might be worth asking a whole new question. What you require is certainly possible though, but will require two keys to be created, one of which will be a concatenation.

Comment: Hi Tim C
Great thank you I will create a new question now.
THank you

Comment: New question added thank you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967181/xsl-for-multiple-xml-lines-within-one-xml-using-grouping-and-keys