# xsl for multiple xml lines within one xml using grouping and keys

Tags: xml, xslt, key, grouping

Please can someone assist with the creation of keys in order to correctly group an xml file using xsl? Using the received xml I need to be able to bring the data into my ERP system whereby a new purchase order is created for each new supplier as well as each destination warehouse. In other words from the below I need a purchase order created for LIY0001 and going to A4 (this must include all lines relevant to both the supplier and warehouse). Similarly a new purchase order needs to be created for WOR0001 going to A4 and another for WOR0001 going to A5 (again with all lines relevant to both keys going to the necessary purchase order grouping as such). For the sample below than there should be 3 separate purchase orders created.

Here is a sample of the xml:

```
<rows>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>LIY0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>5021616</ITEM>
<QTY>528</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>1</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>5.25</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>LIY0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>5021816</ITEM>
<QTY>222</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>2</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>5.90</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>WOR0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A4</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>650616</ITEM>
<QTY>129</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>9</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>4.46</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
<row>
<SUPPLIER>WOR0001</SUPPLIER>
<DESTWHS>A5</DESTWHS>
<RELEASE_DATE>2013-02-14</RELEASE_DATE>
<DUE_DATE>2013-05-13</DUE_DATE>
<ITEM>650610</ITEM>
<QTY>129</QTY>
<LINE_ITEM_NO>1</LINE_ITEM_NO>
<CUST_PO_NO>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CUST_PO_NO>
<PURCHASEPRICE>3.5</PURCHASEPRICE>
</row>
<row>
</rows>
```

Here is the translation file I have created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<PostPurchaseOrders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderHeader> 
      <xsl:for-each select = "rows/row">
      <CustomerPoNumber><xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NO"/></CustomerPoNumber> 
      <Supplier><xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER"/></Supplier>
          <OrderDate><xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_DATE"/></OrderDate>
          <DueDate><xsl:value-of select="DUE_DATE"/></DueDate>
         <Warehouse><xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/></Warehouse>
     </xsl:for-each>
     </OrderHeader> 
      <OrderDetails>
     <xsl:for-each select = "rows/row">
       <StockLine>
         <PurchaseOrderLine><xsl:value-of select="LINE_ITEM_NO"/></PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode><xsl:value-of select="ITEM"/></StockCode>
            <Warehouse><xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS"/></Warehouse>
           <OrderQty><xsl:value-of select="QTY"/></OrderQty>
           <Price><xsl:value-of select="PURCHASEPRICE"/></Price>
          </StockLine>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </OrderDetails>       
       </Orders>
<PostPurchaseOrders>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what I need the xml transformed into for our ERP system:

```
<PostPurchaseOrder>
<Orders>
    <OrderHeader>
        <Supplier>LIY0001</Supplier>
        <CustomerPoNumber>example po</CustomerPoNumber>
        <OrderDate>2013-02-03</OrderDate>
        <Warehouse>A1</Warehouse>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
        <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>1</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>12022</StockCode>
            <OrderQty>10</OrderQty>
        </StockLine>
        <StockLine>
            <PurchaseOrderLine>2</PurchaseOrderLine>
            <StockCode>15014</StockCode>
            <OrderQty>15</OrderQty>
        </StockLine>
    </OrderDetails>
</Orders>
</PostPurchaseOrders>
```

Any help as to how I can change my translation file to group for the 2 keys so that many lines are brought into one purchase order for each supplier as well as per destination warehouse would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies between your XSLT and your example output, so I will emulate the example output.  This should achieve the grouping you are looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kOrder" match="row" use="concat(SUPPLIER, '+', DESTWHS)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <PostPurchaseOrder>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="row[generate-id() = 
                    generate-id(key('kOrder', concat(SUPPLIER, '+', DESTWHS))[1])]"
        mode="group"/>
    </PostPurchaseOrder>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="group">
    <OrderHeader>
      <Supplier>
        <xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER" />
      </Supplier>
      <CustomerPoNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NO" />
      </CustomerPoNumber>
      <OrderDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_DATE" />
      </OrderDate>
      <Warehouse>
        <xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS" />
      </Warehouse>
    </OrderHeader>
    <OrderDetails>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kOrder', concat(SUPPLIER, '+', DESTWHS))" />
    </OrderDetails>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <StockLine>
      <PurchaseOrderLine>
        <xsl:value-of select="LINE_ITEM_NO" />
      </PurchaseOrderLine>
      <StockCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM" />
      </StockCode>
      <OrderQty>
        <xsl:value-of select="QTY" />
      </OrderQty>
    </StockLine>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<PostPurchaseOrder>
  <OrderHeader>
    <Supplier>LIY0001</Supplier>
    <CustomerPoNumber>LIY0001-2013-02-14</CustomerPoNumber>
    <OrderDate>2013-02-14</OrderDate>
    <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
  </OrderHeader>
  <OrderDetails>
    <StockLine>
      <PurchaseOrderLine>1</PurchaseOrderLine>
      <StockCode>5021616</StockCode>
      <OrderQty>528</OrderQty>
    </StockLine>
    <StockLine>
      <PurchaseOrderLine>2</PurchaseOrderLine>
      <StockCode>5021816</StockCode>
      <OrderQty>222</OrderQty>
    </StockLine>
  </OrderDetails>
  <OrderHeader>
    <Supplier>WOR0001</Supplier>
    <CustomerPoNumber>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CustomerPoNumber>
    <OrderDate>2013-02-14</OrderDate>
    <Warehouse>A4</Warehouse>
  </OrderHeader>
  <OrderDetails>
    <StockLine>
      <PurchaseOrderLine>9</PurchaseOrderLine>
      <StockCode>650616</StockCode>
      <OrderQty>129</OrderQty>
    </StockLine>
  </OrderDetails>
  <OrderHeader>
    <Supplier>WOR0001</Supplier>
    <CustomerPoNumber>WOR0001-2013-02-14</CustomerPoNumber>
    <OrderDate>2013-02-14</OrderDate>
    <Warehouse>A5</Warehouse>
  </OrderHeader>
  <OrderDetails>
    <StockLine>
      <PurchaseOrderLine>1</PurchaseOrderLine>
      <StockCode>650610</StockCode>
      <OrderQty>129</OrderQty>
    </StockLine>
  </OrderDetails>
</PostPurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: Hi Mark and JLRishe. Thank you very uch for the answers greatly appreciated. I will give this a go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this as follows with XSLT 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="rows">
        <PostPurchaseOrder>
            <!-- Generate Orders with OrderHeader -->
            <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-by="SUPPLIER">
                <Orders>
                    <OrderHeader>
                        <Supplier><xsl:value-of select="SUPPLIER" /></Supplier>
                        <CustomerPoNumber><xsl:value-of select="CUST_PO_NO" /></CustomerPoNumber>
                        <OrderDate><xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_DATE" /></OrderDate>
                        <Warehouse><xsl:value-of select="DESTWHS" /></Warehouse>
                    </OrderHeader>
                    <!-- Generate OrderDetails -->
                    <OrderDetails>
                        <!-- Generate StockLine -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <StockLine>
                                <PurchaseOrderLine><xsl:value-of select="LINE_ITEM_NO" /></PurchaseOrderLine>
                                <StockCode><xsl:value-of select="ITEM" /></StockCode>
                                <OrderQty><xsl:value-of select="QTY" /></OrderQty>
                            </StockLine>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </OrderDetails>
                </Orders>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </PostPurchaseOrder>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```